# Ubuntu 18.04 freezing frequently

Tags: 18.04, freeze

This issue seems to be quite frequent in Ubuntu. Sometimes (quite often), it happens that my Ubuntu laptop freezes completely.

This happens under heavy load: for example running two instances of IntelliJ and a Gradle build in the background.

However, I have 8GB RAM and i5 Intel running under the hood and this wasn't happening on my second computer with similar configuration and same Ubuntu version (18.04).

Could you advise, how to debug this? Once the system freezes, I cannot do anything apart from turning off the computer completely.

Comment: You could debug this by opening a Terminal and running `dmesg -w`. Then use your computer until it freezes, keeping the Terminal window visible. After it freezes, see what's printed last.

Comment: Edit your question with the `terminal` output of `free -h` and `top` when IntelliJ and Gradle have run for a few minutes. Do you have any GNOME extensions installed? Report back to @heynnema

Comment: The fact you say it happens under heavy load with multiple copies of IntelliJ open and a gradle build running, on a system with only 8Gb ram, makes me thinks it's a ram issue. When it happens run free and see if your swap is getting hammered. If so you will need to increase your swap space.